# Modal Segue Into Navigation Controller with No Nav Bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

In my storyboard I have a view with a segue into a new view that's embedded into a Navigation Controller (so the segue points to the navigation controller).  I have the segue set to a Modal transition, however when the new view is animating up, it contains the standard blue navigation bar above the view (which then animates out of view).

Here's what it looks like mid segue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Iyh3.png

How do I make it so the modal view animates up but without the navigation bar?

I have tried hiding the navigation bar in the embedded view's init, `viewWillAppear`, and `vieWillLoad` methods and that doesn't work.

I event went so far as to create a custom subclass of `UINavigationController` and set the navigation controller in the storyboard to it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This may sound pretty simple, but have you tried hiding the navigation bar immediately before the modal segue starts? I had this problem when presenting a modal view controller and adding a [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES] immediately before the presentation did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem, but I wanted to get a navigation bar for my modal transition, as it was always hidden.
There may be two ways for you to remove the navigation bar:

- Make sure that your view controller is not embed in a navigation controller, as it would put one by default
- Check the "Top Bar" attribute of your previous controller in the workflow and work with none/inferred values depending on your storyboard.

Regards

Comment: Unfortunately I need the view to be in a Nav controller.  For the time being, I simply set the navigationBar.alpha to 0, which apple is adamant about you NOT doing, however its not a private API, nor is it against the terms, so for now I guess I'll have to stick with that. Until I can find a different solution